# Runtime Error but the Code works with test inputs

Tags: python, runtime-error, nested-lists

The code works fine with sample values but while submitting on Hackerrank it shows runtime error. Please help.

```
n=int(input())
marksheet=[]
minimum=[]
for i in range(n):
    name=input()
    score=float(input())
    marksheet.append([name,score])
last=(min(marksheet, key=lambda x:x[1]))
for i in range(n):
    clast=min(marksheet,key=lambda x:x[1])
    if last==clast:
        marksheet.pop()
last2=(min(marksheet,key=lambda x:x[1]))
minimum.append(last2)
marksheet.remove(min(marksheet,key=lambda x:x[1]))
for i in range (len(marksheet)):
    clast2=min(marksheet,key=lambda x:x[1])
    if last2[1]==clast2[1]:
        minimum.append(clast2)
    marksheet.remove(min(marksheet,key=lambda x:x[1]))
minimum.sort()
for item in minimum:
    print (item[0])
```

Comment: What are the sample values? Are you sure input is being taken correctly? Can you get information on what the specific error is?

Comment: Which python version are you running locally and on HackerRank?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This blows up for me: `last2=(min(marksheet,key=lambda x:x[1]))` because you've popped all items off `marksheet` in the line before...

Comment: Sorry for not stating everything. I am using Python3. The test values work fine.The code also works fine on other IDEs.The problem that I'm trying to solve is to fix the runtime error in 8 test cases in Hackerrank while I'm trying to submit. The **marksheet.pop()** before last2 only pops the last element of the marksheet. @JacobIRR

Comment: Add link of your problem sir , Please!